# LDAP: view DIT structure from terminal

Tags: console, ldap, openldap

Can I get list of existing entries using any console utilities?

For example - I can get a tree of my filesystem with `tree`:

```
$ tree
.
├── Catalina
│   └── localhost
│       ├── host-manager.xml
│       └── manager.xml
├── catalina.policy
├── catalina.properties
```

Can I get a similar view with `shelldap`, `ldapsctritps` or builded **OpenLDAP** utils?

Comment: There is this tool, ldapvi: http://www.lichteblau.com/ldapvi/manual/

Comment: It's not directly what You're asking for. https://github.com/david0/ldapbrowse